# How do you iterate through an array in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

Say I have

```
real, dimension(0:100) :: realResults
```

and I want to iterate over `realResults`, ultimately to create json of the array of the form

```
[[x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3, y3], ... ]
```

I'm pretty sure I want to use "do" but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Fortran 90 you can do array iteration like:

```
do i = lbound(realResults, 1), ubound(realResults, 1)
  ! do something with realResults(i)
end do
```

Comment: For that matter most fortran77 compilers since the 1980s have supported this form...

Comment: The Fortran 90 part is in the array support for lbound and ubound. What's even more cool is if you can grok some of the "whole array" functionality, you can do one-liners a la the legendary APL.

Comment: Fortran 90 (I think, maybe 95) also added a ForAll construct. So you can do things like: ForAll (i=1:10) a(i)=b(i)+1

Comment: Use `do i = lbound(columns_to_test, 1), ubound(columns_to_test, 1)`, otherwise you get `Error: Start expression in DO loop at (1) must be a scalar`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like:

```
      do 10 i = 0, 100
C        do something with realResults(i)
  10  continue
```